# Cannot deploy kitchensink

Tags: jboss-eap-7, jboss-developer-studio

I've just downloaded Red Hat Developer Studio
and was searching for a quick way to setup
a H2 database.
So, I found the kitchensink example.
But I cannot deploy it.
I use Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.1
and just right clicked it and added the kitchensink maven project.
Below is the console output:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< org.jboss.quickstarts.eap:jboss-kitchensink-jsp >-----------
[INFO] Building JBoss EAP Quickstart: kitchensink-jsp 7.0.0.GA
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jboss-kitchensink-jsp ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\heilm\workspace\examples\kitchensink-jsp\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jboss-kitchensink-jsp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jboss-kitchensink-jsp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\heilm\workspace\examples\kitchensink-jsp\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.621 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-07T13:54:02+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project jboss-kitchensink-jsp: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project jboss-kitchensink-jsp: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:158)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.JpaDescriptorParser.<init>(JpaDescriptorParser.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.init(JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.java:99)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:674)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:771)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:866)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2100(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:110)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1202)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1311)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1250)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:928)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:142)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 40 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  I've deployed Kitchensink before but after building with Maven I just manually deployed the WAR

Comment: What version of the JDK are you attempting to compile with? It might be missing dependencies if you're trying to compile with Java 11. You might need to use Java 8.

Comment: I think you are compiling using Java 9 or Java 11. You will have to use JDK 8.

Comment: If you are using any other version of JDK other then 8 the dependencies might not get resolved at all.Try with JDK 8 it should work fine.

Comment: Changing to JDK 8 resolved the issue. Thank you all for your help :)